# View chamar @model do controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu utilizo o `EF Design` e importo todos os meus modelos do banco pra um `.EDMX`.

***Pergunto:*** Como faço pra chamar os objetos dos `controllers` que crio, dentro de uma `View`?

Já tentei colocar `@model` até o `controller` e não vai e tentei criar uma lista de um objeto do `controller` também não vai.

Comment: Por favor, coloque como você montou seu controller e sua view pra que a gente possa saber o que fez de errado e te mostrar o que corrigir.

Comment: Na verdade não é a `View` que "chama os objetos dos `controllers`", mas sim ele, o `controllers`, que passam as informações para a `View`. A resposta do @artur-peixoto responde bem sua pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Cara, creio que você não esteja conseguindo passar o objeto para `View`, é isso?

```
//Instância para acessar o banco de dados
private ApplicationDbContext ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();

public ActionResult Details(int Id)
{

    var model = ctx.Objeto.Find(Id)
    return View(model);
}
```

Você coloca o objeto dentro do parâmetro da `view()` e no `HTML` você só coloca o modelo do objeto:

```
@model Solution.Objeto
```

ai depois so chamar o `@Model.Id` ou outra propriedade que queira pegar do objeto.